# Allow user to change their default card with stripe on a Flask app

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I am using all the stripe api subscription structure so that users can subscribe to a plan with the stripe checkout page and manage their permissions depending on their plan.

The thing I don't really get is how to allow users to change their card ?
Because I have seen on the api how to change a card that is already created on stripe but how to clearly allow users to enter new card infos and send them to stripe in a crypted way ?
Is there a stripe structure similar to the checkout page to do so ?
Because I have found nothing.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the user to the Customer Portal :https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management to update their card.

Alternatively, if you use the pre-built checkout page or custom payment flow to collect the new card details (skip the last step about using the payment method / charging the payment method later) : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse. You will then need to set the new PaymentMethod as the [default_payment_method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method) on the Customer, or the [default_payment_method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-default_payment_method) on the Subscription.